# Ionic3 Facebook Login

Tags: ionic3

I am using ionic native Facebook 4 plugin to integrate Facebook login in my ionic 3 app.

Everything is working fine, but there is one issue if I have my Facebook already logged in my device (which is every user has usualy)

Then it returns the following error.

```
errorCode: "4201", errorMessage: "User cancelled dialog"

this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_photos', 'email', 'user_birthday'])
  .then( (res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
// The connection was successful
  if(res.status == "connected") {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Logging in, please wait..."
   });
     loading.present();

      // Get user ID and Token
      var fb_id = res.authResponse.userID;
      var fb_token = res.authResponse.accessToken;

      console.log("FBID : " + fb_id);
      console.log("FB Token : " + fb_token);


      // Get user infos from the API
      this.fb.api("/me?fields=name,gender,birthday,email", []).then((user) => {
```

Comment: can u share your code implementation and all the versions?

Comment: yes i have edited above post

Comment: I have stored user face book id to db as well so next time we need to check if user already in our db ,then direct login them

Comment: cool so what version of plugin you are using?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with facebook login

Comment: Make sure you are using cordova-plugin-facebook4

Comment: yes I am using the cordova-plugin-facebook4 plugin